# Rewrite url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, middleware

I want to have a default controller and default action in my application, so that if a user comes to root he will be served the corresponding page.
For that I made a middleware

```
module.exports = function (controller, action) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // remove any trailing slashes
    req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(/\/$/, "");
    // provide default controller
    if (!req.params.controller) {
      req.originalUrl = '/' + controller;
    }
    // provide default action
    if (!req.params.action) {
      req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl + '/' + action;
    }
    console.log(req.originalUrl); // gives me expected result
    next();
  }
}
```

this is my app code:

```
var router=require(./router())
app.use('/:controller?/:action?',urlMaker(config.defaultController,config.defaultAction));
app.use('/',router);
```

This is router code:

```
var express = require('express');
var globals = require('../globals');

function getRouter() {
  var router = express.Router();
  var controllerList = globals.getController();
  console.log("Creating routes for available controllers");

  for (var name in controllerList) {
    //start creating routes for available controllers
    router.get('/' + name + '/:action', function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("router reached");
      var action = req.params.action;
      controllerList[name][action](req, res);
    });
    console.log("Created route for " + name);
  }

  router.get('/test', function () {
    console.log("hello");
  });

  return router;
}

module.exports = getRouter;
```

What am I doing wrong. Problem is that router does not receive action name. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This simple schema works fine defining `router.js`, `middlewares.js` and `app.js`:

*middlewares.js*

```
function getMiddleware(v1, v2) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    // whatever, you can use v1 and v2 as you wish
    next();
  }
}

module.exports = getMiddleware;
```

*router.js*

```
var express = require('express');

function getRouter(v3) {
  var router = express.Router();
  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // whatever, here you have v if you wish
    res.send('Hello ' + v);
  });
  return router;
}

module.exports = getRouter;
```

*app.js*

```
var middleware = require('./middlewares');
var router = require('./router');
var express = require('express');

// ----
var v1 = v2 = v3 = 42;
// -----
var app = express();

app.use(middleware(v1, v2));
app.use('/', router(v3));
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Once that simple app is running I'd go for the "automatic router definitions" (the `for` loop). Anyway, I suggest not to define a `function` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: When I hardcode a route for Catalog, then it executes fine even after rewrite. But routes created in for loop are not working when i try to reWrite URL. However they work if I directly enter correct url, like localhost:3000/Catalog/index works fine, but not work for localhost:3000